# Relationship in SQL base on a boolean entity(Diagram View)

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship

Consider a table is a pilot's entities and one of them is "NewPilot" which is boolean. If Pilot is new then s/he did not fly any Flight(another table). Now I want to define the relation between Pilot and Flight, which is when Pilot.NewPilot=False has a one to many relationship with flight.

Comment: Your schema is redundant - you can derive the value of NewPilot from the Flight table. If you need to keep a separate field for performance reasons, I suggest you record NumberOfFlights instead and create triggers on the Flight table to keep it in sync.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT pilot.*, 
  CASE when flight.pilot_id is NULL then TRUE 
  else FALSE end as new pilot
FROM pilot
LEFT JOIN flights
on flight.pilot_id = pilot.id
```

Would work like a charm in Oracle. Try it out and let me know if it works on mysql too.

...if not will provide alternate.

Ted.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have the `nvl2()` function but you can use `coalesce()` with other aggregate functions if it needed.

Comment: Thanks @Denniselite, I opted out for case which is simple to read.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL or PostgreSQL you can use something likes:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT pilots.id,
  CASE WHEN
    flights.pilot_id IS NULL
  THEN
    TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS is_new_pilot
FROM pilots
  LEFT JOIN flights ON flights.pilot_id = pilots.id;
```

Where is_new_pilot is a mark about a new pilot. I hope it helps you

Comment: Where? In the `CASE` section? Actually, I suggest it's a normal to read but I'll fix it a little

Comment: no i mean the : sum(coalesce(flights.pilot_id, 0)) = 0

Comment: We should use aggregate function for remove `pilot.id` duplicates from the query results. So `sum(coalesce(flights.pilot_id, 0)) = 0` it is a function which helps us define that nobody of flight contains in result. In your case we have:  `1 false
1 false
1 false
2 true
3 true` I think we need to group by `pilots.id` for our goal, so, SQL needs to use aggregate functions for non-group fields in result

Comment: a DISTINCT added to fix that. Thanks for the comment